# Pandas: subset by filtering for a variable level and group it returning a count?

Tags: python, pandas

I just can't see the wood for the trees syntactically in pandas here.

How do you subset an existing dataframe where you filter for only one level of one variable and group it by another, returning a count of the filtered variable. Presumably this can be done in one operation without needing to create 2 objects.

Below is a reproducible example based on the mtcars dataset. I've modified the 'cyl' and 'am' variables to replicate the levels in my data.

```
                    mpg   cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs  am gear 
Mazda RX4           21.0  six 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  yes   4  
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0  two 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  yes   4  
Datsun 710          22.8  six 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  no    4 
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4  two 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  yes   3 
Hornet Sportabout   18.7  six 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  yes   3 
Valiant             18.1  two 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  yes   3 
Duster 360          14.3  two 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  no    3
```

Here I want to filter for only the cars that are 'yes' from the 'am' column and group them by the 'cyl' levels.

The subset data should look something like this and needs to be a dataframe:

```
cyl   count_column 
six   2
two   3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df[df.am=="yes"].cyl.value_counts()
```

For this you don't really need to group per se, since all you want is the counts.  `df[df.am=="yes"]` gives you just the rows with "yes" in the `am` column.  Then you can use `value_counts` on the `cyl` column of that subset.

The result is a Series.  If you want a DataFrame, make one:

```
pandas.DataFrame({'count_column': df[df.am=="yes"].cyl.value_counts()})
```

Comment: This works perfectly to query but I need the subset data as a manipulable object (dataframe). Have edited original question to reflect this.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "a manipulable object".  The result of `value_counts` is a Series.  If you want it to be a DataFrame, you can call DataFrame and pass the series in.